# I want to perform some task whenever the install button is pressed in Odoo 9 for a module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I tried overriding the `button_install()` method of the model `ir.module.module`

```
class module(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.module.module'

    @api.multi
    def button_install(self):
        raise Warning("----Cannot Install---")
```

But the above method does not execute.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes I have imported the py file but the method does not execute. I dont understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the module formular `button_immediate_install()` is used, try to override this method.

Comment: Because i think his/her code snippet is correct, so maybe he/she is testing with manual module installation. The button on the module formular view is calling `button_immediate_install()`.

Comment: Actually overriding `button_install` could stop odoo working on restart, because on module loading, this method is used.

Comment: I tried overriding the button_immediate_install() method also the same way but even it didn't work. I want to apply certain validation checks when we press the install button for the module.

Comment: It worked. Overriding button_immediate_install() method solved the problem. I made a slight syntax error. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: @Adityasharma Please can you give us that syntax error.

Comment: class module(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'ir.module.module'

 @api.multi
 def button_immediate_install(self):
  for obj in self:
   raise Warning("--INSTALLING--")
  return super(module, self).button_immediate_install()

This code worked for me.

Comment: @CZoellner How can I achieve this is Odoo13 because I tried above way like create a new file in models are write the last commented code there but didn't work for me any suggestion